# How to detect resizing of ttk.Treeview column?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I have a `ttk.Notebook` and each tab contains a `ttk.Treeview`. All treeviews have the same columns but contain different items, like in the code below.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
notebook.pack()

tree1 = ttk.Treeview(notebook, columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
tree1.insert('', 'end', text='item1', values=('a1', 'b1', 'c1'))
tree2 = ttk.Treeview(notebook, columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
tree2.insert('', 'end', text='item2', values=('a2', 'b2', 'c2'))
tree2.insert('', 'end', text='item2', values=('a2', 'b2', 'c2'))

notebook.add(tree1, text='Tab 1')
notebook.add(tree2, text='Tab 2')

root.mainloop()
```

I would like all trees to always have the same column widths. So, for instance, when the user resizes the column 'a' of `tree1`, the column 'a' of `tree2` should be resized too.

I know I can get the size of a column with
`tree1.column('a', 'width')` and set it  with `tree2.column('a', width=300)`.

But how can I detect that the size of a column has changed?

I have checked that the treeview `<Configure>` event is not triggered by a column resizing.

Comment: If you care just for user interaction, you can bind a call back to `<B1-Motion>` event and check `identify_region(event.x, event.y)`. If it returns `'separator'` - get `iid` of the column via `identify_column(event.x)` and `width` after that. Create a function, wich would iterate over all columns of a specified widget with specified width. If you change `width` programmatically - just call that function. If it changes via user -  `<B1-Motion>` should handle it.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like a good idea. However, I don't know how hard it would hit a perfomance and how responsive a `treeview` would be, obviously it depends on implementation. However, another option is to bind to `<ButtonRelease-1>` with same logic to prevent a possible perfomance issue.

Comment: Might be an interesting thing to solve this with `ttk::treeview::Press`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following CommonSense suggestions, I have made a binding on `<ButtonRelease-1>` to check if a column has been resized. If `tree.identify_region(event.x, event.y)` is `'separator'` then there was a resizing. Then I need to identify the columns on both sides of the separator.
`tree.identify_column(event.x)` gives me the column on the left in the form `'#<column number>'` and from it I can get the id of the column on the right.
Finally, I execute the function that resize the columns in all trees.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()


def on_click_release(event):
    tree = event.widget
    if tree.identify_region(event.x, event.y) == 'separator':
        left_column = tree.identify_column(event.x)
        right_column = '#%i' % (int(tree.identify_column(event.x)[1:]) + 1)
        width_l = tree.column(left_column, 'width')
        width_r = tree.column(right_column, 'width')
        for tree2 in trees:
            if tree2 != tree:
                tree2.column(left_column, width=width_l)
                tree2.column(right_column, width=width_r)


notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
notebook.pack()

trees = [ttk.Treeview(notebook, columns=['a', 'b', 'c']) for i in range(4)]

for i, tree in enumerate(trees):
    tree.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', on_click_release)
    notebook.add(tree, text='Tab %i' % i)

root.mainloop()
```

**EDIT**: I realized that the above method does not work if we move the column separator too quickly (`tree.identify_region(event.x, event.y)` does not return 'separator'). So I have found a different method: When the user changes tab, then the width of each column of the current tab is set to the width of the corresponding column of the previously visible tab.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


def tab_changed(event):
    global current_tab
    tab = notebook.index('current')  # get newly visible tab number
    tree1 = trees[current_tab]  # get previously visible tree
    tree2 = trees[tab]   # get newly visible tree
    cols = ('#0', ) + tree1.cget('columns')  # tuple of all columns
    for column in cols:
        tree2.column(column, width=tree1.column(column, 'width'))
    current_tab = tab


root = tk.Tk()
notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
notebook.pack()

trees = [ttk.Treeview(notebook, columns=['a', 'b', 'c']) for i in range(4)]
current_tab = 0  # store currently visible tab number

for i, tree in enumerate(trees):
    notebook.bind('<<NotebookTabChanged>>', tab_changed)
    notebook.add(tree, text='Tab %i' % i)

root.mainloop()
```